# Course Curriculam particular day particular hours no class

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible to define a particular day particular hours (example, 5 and 6) are no classes? in opta course curricula planner.

Tried the following approach, doesn't work.

```
rule "saturdayHalfDay"
    when
        Lecture( period!=null, $day:period.getDay(),
        $day!=null,$time:period.getTimeslot(),
        $time!=null,
        $day.getDayIndex()==5,
        ($time.getTimeslotIndex()==5 || $time.getTimeslotIndex()==4) 
        )   

    then
     System.out.println(" $day " + $day + " $time " + $time);
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

//assume that $day.getDayIndex()==5 (5 is saturday)

Answer (score 0):

If you start from the Curriculum Course scheduling example, you'll see that some datasets don't have a Timeslot for 12:00 to 13:00, because there are no classes during lunch. So it's simply a matter of not adding a Timeslot for those hours.

It becomes more interesting if some Courses can't be scheduled during a certain Timeslot. Simply create a `TimeslotCoursePenatly` object (see the `Penatly` classes in other examples) to be able to put an unwanted combination in the dataset. Then add a score rules that checks that lowers the hard score for each `Penalty` that is violated.

Comment: "Penatly " classes example, unable to find this class in opta planner. could you please provide more detail on this?

Comment: Go to [https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner), press the button "t" and type "Penalty".

Comment: I tried the following approach, doesnt work. any suggestions?
rule "saturdayHalfDay"
    when
        Lecture( period!=null, $day:period.getDay(),
  $day!=null,$time:period.getTimeslot(),
  $time!=null,
  $day.getDayIndex()==5,
  ($time.getTimeslotIndex()==5 || $time.getTimeslotIndex()==4) 
  )   

    then
     System.out.println(" $day " + $day + " $time " + $time);
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//assume that $day.getDayIndex()==5 (5 is saturday)